# Bug-out- bag among list of new words

Tags: dictionaries

I was just informed on CBS news that this is now an official word. Is the label 'word' appropriate for a group of words strung together with hyphens,  or is there a more accurate term?

Comment: Monstrosity? Frankenword?!

Comment: Adjective or noun phrase? Maybe compound noun?

Comment: In programming, formatting a string of words separated by hyphens is called "kebab-case"

Comment: How do you define a word?

Comment: How do you feel about "will-o'-the-wisp"?

Comment: Being recorded in a dictionary does not make it an “official” word. It just makes it a word recorded in a dictionary. There is no such thing as an “official” word.

Answer (score 1):

They are "[hyphenated compound words](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/)." (grammarly)

> When two words are used together to yield a new meaning, a compound is formed. Compound words can be written in three ways: as open compounds (spelled as two words, e.g., ice cream), closed compounds (joined to form a single word, e.g., doorknob), or hyphenated compounds (two words joined by a hyphen, e.g., long-term). Sometimes, more than two words can form a compound (e.g., mother-in-law).

See also:
**Hyphen** ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen))

> Hyphens are used in many compound words to show that the component words have a combined meaning (e.g. a pick-me-up, mother-in-law, good-hearted) or that there is a relationship between the words that make up the compound: for example, rock-forming minerals are minerals that form rocks. But you don’t need to use them in every type of compound word.

and, the very definition of "***word***", on [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/word_1):

> **1. b.** a letter or group of letters representing such a unit of language, written or printed usually in solid or hyphenated form

Comment: As for the usage of "word" in cited context, it's a broader sense that includes any expression.